# How to set password and username for ARM template source control type property

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a ARM template ,in which contains a resource which pull the code from github. My question is how to set username and password for this github in arm template. My repo is not public.

```
 "gitRepoUrl": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The URL to the GitHub repository to deploy."
  },
  "defaultValue": "https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-quickresponses.git"
},
"gitBranch": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The branch of the GitHub repository to deploy."
  },
  "defaultValue": "master"
}
"resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
          "name": "web",
          "type": "sourcecontrols",
          "condition": "[not(empty(parameters('gitRepoUrl')))]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('botAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "RepoUrl": "[parameters('gitRepoUrl')]",
            "branch": "[parameters('gitBranch')]",
            "IsManualIntegration": true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

reference arm template [ARM TEMPLATE](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-quickresponses/blob/master/Deployment/azuredeploy.json)

Any hep?

Comment: Did you tried using Oauth token instead of username & password ? You can use [SourceControlProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sourcecontrols?tabs=json#sourcecontrolproperties-object) property for that.

Comment: i created a access token from github so it it like this way
"properties": {
            "RepoUrl": "[parameters('gitRepoUrl')]",
            "branch": "[parameters('gitBranch')]",
            "IsManualIntegration": true,
            "token":'xxxxxxxx'
          },
but its failed.

Comment: "Cannot find SourceControlToken with name GitHub."

Comment: Check this [template format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sourcecontrols?tabs=json#template-format) for more reference.

Comment: You can generate token from GitHub and the pass it to the template format which @AbhinandanBharamgunde has shared.

Comment: @AbhinandanBharamgunde thanks for the format. Can you post this with an example. property fields are not mandatory . SO i created the access token through  https://github.com/settings/tokens. and set token key with this created value. remaining fields are removed.